# same 2 strings with different result

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to Python (and Flask) and have a strange problem with strings.
Hope someone can tell me why the 2nd code part don't work, when both give the same output with print ?
the 2nd part only give blanks in the dropdown list.
Thx in advance for your support.

this works:

```
test=[{'name':'green.tmp'}, {'name':'red.tmp'}, {'name':'blue.tmp'}, {'name':' '}]
count = 0
for character in temp:
    count += 1
print(count)  # 81
print(test)   # [{'name':'green.tmp'}, {'name':'red.tmp'}, {'name':'blue.tmp'}, {'name':' '}]

return render_template('test_index.html', data=test )
```

this don't work:

```
path = "/var/lib/mpd/music/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
temp = "[{'name': '"
for file in dirs:
    temp = temp + file + "'}, {'name': '"
temp = temp + " '}]"
count = 0
for character in temp:
    count += 1
print(count)  # 81
print(temp)   # [{'name':'green.tmp'}, {'name':'red.tmp'}, {'name':'blue.tmp'}, {'name':' '}]

return render_template('test_index.html', data=str(temp) )
```

Comment: You can't construct a dictionary like a string. It's going to be a string then.

Comment: @KlausD. but OP does cast both to ``str`` anyway when calling ``render_template``

Comment: @MikeScotty I guess the OP has not understood the concept of dictionaries so far and handles them like strings.

Comment: @KlausD. sorry, the 'str' shuld not be in the working part.

Comment: @MikeScotty you are rigth, I will try read about dictionaries , thx

Comment: Oh, well, with the updated question it's now clear what's the difference. (list of dict vs pure str object).

Comment: You cannot build a string that "looks like" a dict and then treat it the same way that you treat a dict, for the same reason that you cannot paint a picture of a person and then have a meaningful conversation with that person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of constructing the dict like a string, try this instead.

```
dirs = os.listdir(path)
temp = []
for dir in dirs:
    temp.append({'name': dir})
print(temp)
```